# Menu showing in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE my menu display like below image. If menu length is short then two menu comes together.

how to solve this menu.

My CSS code:

```
.module-content{ float:left;margin: 8px 11px 4px;}

.module-content ul{   float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 0px; width: 99%;}  

.module-content ul li{list-style:none;  background: url("../images/red-arrow.png") 0 5px no-repeat; padding-left:12px;}

.module-content ul li a{  color: #393939; font: 12px Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;}

.module-content ul li a:hover{  color: #EF2030; }
```

[image]

Comment: @Pramod: Statistics will lie to you. If you actually look at the OP's prior questions, you'll see that most do not yet have answers that have helped the OP. It's therefore _correct_ that he didn't accept answers to those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of `.module-content ul li` to the same width as `module-content ul`.

Comment: Could you also post the html?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you make .module-content ul li the same width as .module-content ul, .module-content ul li has also 'display: block'